# How to use expression as condition in match?

Tags: rust, match

How do I use an expression in a match arm?  I want to handle the case of `100` being equal to `75 + 25`.

```rust
fn main() {
    match 100 {
        75 + 25 => println!("100"),
//         ^ expected one of `...`, `..=`, `..`, `=>`, `if`, or `|`
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
}
```

Comment: This might have the best answer already, but you might also be interested in `x if x == 75 + 25 => …`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you can not do this without using unstable features on the nightly compiler.

What you can write is:

```
fn main() {
    const A: i32 = 75 + 25;
    match 100 {
        A => println!("100"),
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
}
```

or as [@Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629531/how-to-use-expression-as-condition-in-match/68629766#comment121287972_68629531) comments you can use a guard:

```
fn main() {
    match 100 {
        x if x == 75 + 25 => println!("100"),
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
}
```

However, if I was putting a complicated expression in the guard and it was in a performance-critical region, I'd be careful to check that the compiler was properly extracting it as a constant. (Should be OK if you limit yourself to const-functions...)

A new feature to support something like what you want is called `inline-const` and is being tracked [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76001), and you can find some details [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2920-inline-const.html). If you're willing to use unstable features on the nightly compiler then you can do this now:

```
#![feature(inline_const)]
fn main() {
    match 100 {
        const {75 + 25} => println!("100"),
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
}
```

When/if it becomes stable you can remove the `feature` line, which enables the unstable feature.